# AutoLayout container relative position not recognised under ios8 beta 4

Tags: objective-c, position, autolayout, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

In my view, I init a view like this:

```
UIView *statsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 130, 200, 12)];
```

Inside this view, I create 3 autolayout subviews contained in this previous view.

```
    for (UIButton* v in [statsView subviews]) {
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       [statsView addSubview:v];
    }
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"reposts": v1,
                            @"likes": v2,
                            @"comments": v3
                            };
    [statsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[reposts][likes][comments]"
                               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop| NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                               metrics:0
                               views:views]];
```

On IOS7 , the Y position of the container is 130 (defined in the initWithFrame),  but with ios8, the Y position looks like "0".

Any ideas?

Comment: Same here. Could you come up with anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask an other question about the same problem and Saldorino give me a good answer

[Xcode6 - Autolayout view in an other autolayout view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892293/xcode6-autolayout-view-in-an-other-autolayout-view/25894916#25894916)

The issue lies in the missing the vertical position constraint.

```
[statsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[comments]"
                           options:0
                           metrics:0
                           views:views]];
```