# Xcode6 - Autolayout view in an other autolayout view

Tags: autolayout, constraints, ios8, parent, nslayoutconstraint

This problem didn't exist on xCode 5 even with ios8.

**The green square** have to be **in the red square** cause the greenView is a subview of the red view. But built with xCode6 **the position of the greenView is not relative** to its parent.

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


/**** 1 - REDVIEW, THE CONTAINER *****/

UIView *redView = [UIView new];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:redView];

UIView *spaceView = [UIView new];
spaceView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:spaceView];


NSDictionary *views = @{@"spaceView" : spaceView,
                        @"redView": redView};

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[spaceView]|"
                            options: 0
                            metrics:0
                            views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[spaceView][redView]|"
                            options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                            metrics:0
                            views:views]];


//CENTER VERTICALY
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:redView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:spaceView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  multiplier:1
                                  constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];


/**** 1 - GREENBUTTON, IN THE CONTAINER *****/

UIButton *greenButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
greenButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
greenButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[greenButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[redView addSubview:greenButton];

views = @{@"button" : greenButton};

[redView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[button(35)]|"
                                options: 0
                                metrics:0
                                views:views]];



}
```

Where is the trouble? 
(you can copy and paste those line to try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints defined are positioning the greenButton relative to its superview. The issue lies in the missing the vertical position constraint. Also note that the visual syntax you used resulted in conflicting constraints:

- 0 distance to leading
- 0 distance to trailing (I removed this one to make it work)
- width of 35
- superview of witdth != 35;

If you use the following constraints for the greenButton, it will be placed top-left on its parent.

```
[redView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[button(35)]"
                             options: 0
                             metrics:0
                             views:views]];

[redView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[button(35)]"
                             options:0
                             metrics:0
                             views:views]];
```